# PayPal Reference transactions on Live Account

Tags: paypal

We have succesfully integrated PayPal on our Website and I contacted PayPal over MTS to enable Reference transaction on our Live Account, they told me I must contact Customer support and they after mutliple Mail sent still don't have a clue what I want.

On our Live Account we got:
[LongMessage] => Merchant not enabled for reference transactions
[ErrorCode] => 11452

Can someone point me who I can contact to have them enabled?

Comment: Have you tried calling support? You should be able to get in touch with the right department to hash this out.

Comment: @Dennis Yes, I tried to reach them three times but I had must leave the office as the time I had to wait on phone was too long (50, 140, 70 minutes). I will try on Monday again and hope they understand what I want.